# Book -possibly YA -from late 1970's where a plague had blinded most adults -some people lived in domed cities - called the "Ceph"

Tags: story-identification

-a keratophagic staph infection? Seems to have mentioned a parking lot full of 1988 Buicks -set about 1994? Thanks!

Comment: This reminds me of the backstory of Kidworld (https://projects.inklesspen.com/fatal-and-friends/hostile-v/kidworld/)

Comment: Were the cities called the "Ceph" or the plague?

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not a perfect match I wonder if this could be [Systemic Shock](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1057) by Dean Ing.

This was written in 1981 and is set in 1996, so it matches your timescale. The summary on Goodreads is:

> As the Soviet menace collapses, China and India join forces and launch a devastating nuclear attack on America. And in the lawless anarchy that follows, one young man learns the hard way that the man most likely to survive is the one who learns to kill.

It does feature a keratophagic staph plague that does cause blindness:

> My current work is with something by the jawbreaking monicker of *Staphylococcus rosacea*, alias Keratophagic Staph, and we can thank God it's still confined to Asia. I'm assuming you've heard about it; it's in the news here. On the other hand: if you're anywhere in its vicinity, burn used hankies, keep your resistance up and your hands away from your eyes.

But I don't think the term *Ceph* is used in the book, and I can't find any mention of a parking lot full of 1988 Buicks.